# bash script run with eval shows no output until it's done

Tags: bash, eval

script.sh:

```
cmd=( python script.py "'$param1'" "'$param2'" )
echo "before python script"
eval "${cmd[@]}"
echo "after python script"
```

script.py:

```
print "entering python script"
...
prompt the user
```

My problem is script.py shows no output until it is finished. The reason it's a problem is because script.py contains a prompt for the user to select something so I need output to be shown immediately. Every time I run this though it shows "before script", no prompt shows, I enter my input blindly, and only when it's complete does the prompt and the rest of the python script's output appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bash command:

```
cmd=( python script.py "'$param1'" "'$param2'" )
```

means:

> Run `python script.py` passing it as arguments the values of `$param1` and `$param2` each surrounded by single quotes, and capture the output (`stdout`). After the command finishes, split the captured output into words and put them into the shell array variable `cmd`, one word per element.

Normally, if you need to use a prompt, you would write it to `stderr`, in case `stdout` is being redirected or captured, as in your command line. Otherwise, the prompt is just treated as any other output and you'll never see it.